# Can a laptop with a tablet feature be used as a controller for racing games?

Tags: controllers, windows

I have a laptop (Lenovo Yoga 15) which can be turned into a tablet (using the same OS[Windows 10]), and I was wondering if I could play any racing games using the laptop itself as a controller?  Is this possible?

Comment: Any racing game you can download from the Windows store should work. If you're asking about the big games, you'll have to use a real gamepad, or be lucky to find a game that can work with tablet hardware only.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So, games like Dirt 3 or Euro Truck Simulator 2 wouldn't work, right ?

Comment: [The laptop specifications](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/yoga-series/yoga-15/#tab-features) don't mention anything about motion sensors in the laptop but rather that it uses RealSense which `allowing you to command your computer without touching it`. So the laptop isn't the controller but your hands or whatever the laptop detects.

Comment: I think the laptop does have a motion sensor because when I flip my laptop then the screen rotates with it.

Comment: Maybe but it probably can't be used as a motion controller or it would be advertised... or they're holding on that because their drivers or something else is holding them to offer that feature.

Comment: It does say that it has a G-Sensor, that's what android uses right ? http://shop.lenovo.com/gb/en/tech-specs/tablets/thinkpad-yoga-15/

Comment: To the close vote for off-topic : this is not asking for a recommendation. This is a simple question calling for a "yes" or "no" answer. Also, it is nice to leave a comment with your vote.

Comment: @Ealhad 1) Comments are, and always will be, optional.Tim's lost his keys again.  2) A question that is answered literally with only a yes or no doesn't meet the minimum character limit, so it carries the implicit request to flesh it out with more details. I can easily see how someone could take it as a recommendation. Not that I agree with it, but I can see it.

Comment: @Frank I can see it too. And I know comments are not mandatory when voting - since you *can* vote without commenting :)